# Get-PnPField on the web/site level and not on the list level. is this possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this PnP Powershell script to get a field on the list level and hide it from the New form:-

```
Connect-PnPOnline <tenant-site-url>

$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$field = Get-PnPField -Identity <field-name> -List <list-name>

$field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$field.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

but how i can get the field on the web/site level, instead on the list level. so i can set this property for the field on the web/site level and get it applied to all the lists?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've never really used PnP Powershell, but at a guess, I'd say just omit the `-List` parameter.

If you look at the [documentation for that command (`Get-PnPField`)](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPField.html), the very first example has *no* parameters, and says that it:

> Gets all the fields from the current site

So it seems that it *can* get fields from the site level.

And the third example shows using the `-Group` parameter to get all fields in a specific group, but that example also does not use the `-List` parameter, and says (emphasis mine):

> Gets all the fields for the group called Custom Columns **for the site**
> currently connected to

And if you read the details about the `-List` parameter, it says it's optional, so... you don't *have* to use it to specify a list.  It would sem logical that if you don't specify a list, it's going to look at the site level.